# How to set tab order for array of cluster,where cluster elements have different data types in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

Labview

[image]

i have one array of cluster and 1D array. i need to set tab order for combination for array of cluster elements and 1 D array.

> **Array of Cluster data types:string and time,1d array has only Boolean.**

please see image above.

Comment: Add your image into the post instead of a link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the tab order of the cluster, right click on the cluster and select "Reorder Controls In Cluster..." When the VI is running, if you have focus within one element of the cluster, you can tab within the cluster.

There is no built-in keyboard support in LabVIEW for tabbing between elements of an array when those elements are clusters. There is also no built-in support for tabbing out of one array into another array. You will need to add an Event structure to your block diagram and use it to watch for the Tab key being pressed and then perform your own change of focus. [This example code may be useful to you.](http://%20https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Programs/Customize-the-Tabbing-Behavior-of-a-VI-by-an-Event-Structure/ta-p/3502330)

The array control does not really work well for UI interaction. It is meant mostly as a way of displaying data and of passing data into subVIs. You may find yourself frustrated if you try to control the tabbing manually too much. It is an area where it will probably be useful to ask for help [on the NI LabVIEW forum](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/bd-p/170) for someone who can help you step-by-step to design a UI. I've been using LV for decades, and this is an area that still frustrates me.